# Is there a way in obj-c cocoa to create a AES-128 encryption key file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, encryption, aes, crypt

In my mac application i have to encrypt a file using a AES-128 encryption key

I thought of using http://www.aescrypt.com/download/ to do so.

But i need the encryption key file first

The bottom line is this

1. Generate a key file from my mac app (this is the vital step i need)
2. Use the key file to encrypt a file say abcd.mpg
3. Store the key in secure place
4. Fetch the key and decrpyt

Comment: You should look at `CommonCrypto` which is part of the OS X libraries for the encryption/decryption and you should investigate the `KeyChain` for storing the key.

Comment: This won't be secure unless you use the correct cipher mode and authenticate the data.  There are thousands of ways to screw this up, only a couple of ways to do it correctly, and it sounds like you don't know what you're getting into.  The odds are against you.

Answer (score 0):

Creation of keys requires only knowing how long the key needs to be and having a good source of randomness.  In the case of OS X, there's a good `/dev/random` that is considered to contain sufficient entropy that reading from it for cryptographic purposes is reasonable.   You read from it just like any other device.

Encryption (and decryption) can be done under 10.5 and later using Common Crypto, and in 10.7 and later using Security Transforms, both are reasonably well documented (Search for `Cryptographic Services` for a good overview).

For key storage (as was mentioned by @mttrb), the KeyChain is the right choice on OS X, and if you need to allow the user to save off the key separately, you might consider packaging it in a passworded container.

Although Common Crypto can be used through 10.8, Security Transforms allow chaining and are a bit better designed for dealing with streamed data and larger files.